# How to fetch the data which was sent via WM_COPYDATA into VB6 application?

Tags: vba, vb6

I have referred to code in this article to send messages from 1 C#.NET application to another C#.NET application using win32 api (SendMessage, FindWindow, WM_COPYDATA) [MSDN code sample application](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSSendWMCOPYDATA-97e6644e)

**My requirement is that the target app is an VB6 application ( we have access to its source code).. I am using following code to send message to the VB6 exe application. But, how do I receive the message in VB6 application? (Following are codes in C#.NET to send/receive message)**

Code for sending message:-

```
#region Using directives
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
#endregion


namespace CSSendWM_COPYDATA
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Find the target window handle.
            IntPtr hTargetWnd = NativeMethod.FindWindow(null, "CSReceiveWM_COPYDATA");
            if (hTargetWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to find the \"CSReceiveWM_COPYDATA\" window", 
                    "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

            // Prepare the COPYDATASTRUCT struct with the data to be sent.
            MyStruct myStruct;

            int nNumber;
            if (!int.TryParse(this.tbNumber.Text, out nNumber))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid value of Number!");
                return;
            }

            myStruct.Number = nNumber;
            myStruct.Message = this.tbMessage.Text;

            // Marshal the managed struct to a native block of memory.
            int myStructSize = Marshal.SizeOf(myStruct);
            IntPtr pMyStruct = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(myStructSize);
            try
            {
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(myStruct, pMyStruct, true);

                COPYDATASTRUCT cds = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
                cds.cbData = myStructSize;
                cds.lpData = pMyStruct;

                // Send the COPYDATASTRUCT struct through the WM_COPYDATA message to 
                // the receiving window. (The application must use SendMessage, 
                // instead of PostMessage to send WM_COPYDATA because the receiving 
                // application must accept while it is guaranteed to be valid.)
                NativeMethod.SendMessage(hTargetWnd, WM_COPYDATA, this.Handle, ref cds);

                int result = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                if (result != 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format(
                        "SendMessage(WM_COPYDATA) failed w/err 0x{0:X}", result));
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pMyStruct);
            }
        }


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal struct MyStruct
        {
            public int Number;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
            public string Message;
        }


        #region Native API Signatures and Types

        /// <summary>
        /// An application sends the WM_COPYDATA message to pass data to another 
        /// application
        /// </summary>
        internal const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;


        /// <summary>
        /// The COPYDATASTRUCT structure contains data to be passed to another 
        /// application by the WM_COPYDATA message. 
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct COPYDATASTRUCT
        {
            public IntPtr dwData;       // Specifies data to be passed
            public int cbData;          // Specifies the data size in bytes
            public IntPtr lpData;       // Pointer to data to be passed
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// The class exposes Windows APIs to be used in this code sample.
        /// </summary>
        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        internal class NativeMethod
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Sends the specified message to a window or windows. The SendMessage 
            /// function calls the window procedure for the specified window and does 
            /// not return until the window procedure has processed the message. 
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="hWnd">
            /// Handle to the window whose window procedure will receive the message.
            /// </param>
            /// <param name="Msg">Specifies the message to be sent.</param>
            /// <param name="wParam">
            /// Specifies additional message-specific information.
            /// </param>
            /// <param name="lParam">
            /// Specifies additional message-specific information.
            /// </param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg,
                IntPtr wParam, ref COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);


            /// <summary>
            /// The FindWindow function retrieves a handle to the top-level window 
            /// whose class name and window name match the specified strings. This 
            /// function does not search child windows. This function does not 
            /// perform a case-sensitive search.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="lpClassName">Class name</param>
            /// <param name="lpWindowName">Window caption</param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Code for receiving message:-

```
#region Using directives
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
#endregion


namespace CSReceiveWM_COPYDATA
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_COPYDATA)
            {
                // Get the COPYDATASTRUCT struct from lParam.
                COPYDATASTRUCT cds = (COPYDATASTRUCT)m.GetLParam(typeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));

                // If the size matches
                if (cds.cbData == Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct)))
                {
                    // Marshal the data from the unmanaged memory block to a 
                    // MyStruct managed struct.
                    MyStruct myStruct = (MyStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(cds.lpData, 
                        typeof(MyStruct));

                    // Display the MyStruct data members.
                    this.lbNumber.Text = myStruct.Number.ToString();
                    this.lbMessage.Text = myStruct.Message;
                }
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal struct MyStruct
        {
            public int Number;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
            public string Message;
        }


        #region Native API Signatures and Types

        /// <summary>
        /// An application sends the WM_COPYDATA message to pass data to another 
        /// application.
        /// </summary>
        internal const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;


        /// <summary>
        /// The COPYDATASTRUCT structure contains data to be passed to another 
        /// application by the WM_COPYDATA message. 
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct COPYDATASTRUCT
        {
            public IntPtr dwData;       // Specifies data to be passed
            public int cbData;          // Specifies the data size in bytes
            public IntPtr lpData;       // Pointer to data to be passed
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also in Microsoft [How To Pass String Data Between Applications Using SendMessage](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176058/en-us)

Comment: The article mentions of how to do it in VB6. However; it doesnot show how to pull in a structure into VB6 which is sent from C#.NET link I posted in my question. And the link in my question does not show how to send message into buffer so that I can refer to example in your reference link.. Please guide..

Comment: @NachiketKamat, the sample in article shows how to code the target (receiving) and the sending part. What is sent is a buffer of data. If it is a string, a struct, or any other thing it depends of the development. So, you need to serialize your struct into a buffer in your c# app, and deserialize it in your vb6 app

Comment: Yes MC ND, I need to pass a simple string into the vb6 app.. do you advice to serialize the string and desirealize? Or would it be better off to stick with struct and serialize/deserialize the strict?

Comment: @NachiketKamat, if all you need is to pass a string, the sample code shows how to do it (a$ in the code). The serialize/deserialize is just a way of dealing with the struct, not needed for the string.

Comment: Besides copy memory, the structure holds the pointer to this memory isnt it?

Comment: @NachiketKamat, no need for copymemory in the sending part. You are using `Marshal.StructureToPtr` to do the same work. Copy the data from the structure to a memory buffer.

Comment: Thanks, I copied the string value into byte array;used marshal.allochglobal(sizeofarray);marshal.copy();then, used the COPYDATASTRUCT and passed it as a ref argument of the SENDMESSAGE... On VB6 side, followed code in your article.. thanks